# Clarification on infinite mass/momentum argument

Tags: special-relativity, mass, speed-of-light, momentum

While reasoning that why a particle can not be accelerated to light speed $c$, it is argued that the mass/momentum approaches infinity as speed approaches $c$. I think it is per GR.

I am sure this also fits into mathematics, otherwise people would not be making this argument.

I may be wrong, and please feel free to correct me if you think so. But I do not think that is the case - i.e. mass/momentum does not approach infinite.

My simple argument is - if the mass/momentum of a moving particle approaches infinite and such a particle moving at speeds close to $c$, then it would be almost impossible to stop that particle. In other words, it should be equally difficult/impossible to slow it down.

We all know that though it is not possible to accelerate the particle further, but it is no big deal to slow it down. Slowing down an infinite mass/momentum would not be that easy. **Infinite mass reasoning must apply both ways - in speeding up as well as in slowing down. Has it been experimentally shown that it also applies to slowing down at limits close to $c$?**

Therefore, I can argue that mass/momentum does not approach infinite, it is the forces that are rendered ineffective at such speeds because the force itself propagates at $c$ and can not accelerate anything as fast as itself, or faster. Force is rendered ineffective only in direction of motion (acceleration), not in opposite direction (slowing down).

**Analogy how force may become ineffective** - In a way, we can not accelerate a car that is already going at 300 miles/hr by pushing with our hands, because humans can not move their hand as fast. But we can accelerate a car going at 5 miles an hour. As the speed gets closer and closer to that of force $c$, the force can not push it any more. Same way as we can not move our hand faster than 300 miles/hr and can not accelerate that car by pushing on it. But slowing down would be effective, dangerous and fatal though.

Please correct if I am missing something, instead of blank down voting.

**Considering formula given by John Rennie in his answer -**

===========================================================

The momentum of an object of mass $m$ moving at velocity $v$ is:

$$ p = \gamma m v = \frac{mv}{\sqrt{1 - \frac{v^2}{c^2}}} $$

which goes to infinity as $v \to c$. In the limit of $v \ll c$ the Lorentz factor $\gamma \approx 1$ and we recover the Newtonian approximation.

===========================================================

Same math can be applied to effectiveness of the force. *Only thing is that v is the velocity (only positive) component in the direction of the force. So, for slowing down, it will be 0, or $\gamma \approx 1$*

The effective force $F1$ when particle is moving at velocity $v$ and a force $F$ is applied:

$$ F = \gamma F1 = \frac{F1}{\sqrt{1 - \frac{v^2}{c^2}}} $$

This way, the math does not change either.

So at limits close to $c$, the force must be fully effective in slowing down and pretty much ineffective in accelerating.

**I am proposing below experiment to prove/disprove the concept. If someone is aware of such an experiment being done, please share the results.**

1. Make a particle accelerate at ~highest speed that the accelerator can achieve.
2. Once this ~speed is achieved, continue to apply the force for another 1 minute. The particle should gain negligible speed during this 1 minute, but should gain a lot of momentum (per momentum formula)
3. Now stop the accelerating force and start an equal slowing force. I.e. reverse the force.

Per the current (infinite mass/momentum) explanation, 1 minute of slowing should reduce the speed by negligible – same speed that was gained during last 1 minute of acceleration. Because force is rate of change of momentum and same force in both directions should cause same change of momentum/speed during same amount of time.

But per my explanation, a lot more slowing down will take place during the 1 minute because gamma becomes zero for slowing down.

I think evidence and results of such experiment being done, can answer this question definitively. But equivalent other answers would help too - like evidence of the 7 Tev energy of protons being physically measured rather than just being calculated via the momentum formula.

Comment: In addition to John's answer, this blog article  is very helpful, imo: https://profmattstrassler.com/articles-and-posts/particle-physics-basics/mass-energy-matter-etc/more-on-mass/the-two-definitions-of-mass-and-why-i-use-only-one/

Comment: Large and infinity are different things. And the reasoning applies both ways:  the amount of momentum that you need to transfer to speed up the particle is the same you need to stop it.

Comment: *"Only thing is that v is the velocity component in the direction of the force. So, for slowing down, it will be 0, or $\gamma\approx 1$"* No. You use $-v$, which gives you the same gamma because velocity enters squared. Seriously. See my comment under John's answer about energy recovery linacs. We really do know what we are talking about with the stuff.

Comment: @dmckee: I read about the ERL. Although it slows down electrons, but the comparison of how much slowing happens during same amount of time as for acceleration is not mentioned. The purpose of ERL seems different from comparing acceleration vs slowing down. Slowing down will recover energy, there is no doubt but how much is the question. On $v$ comment - I am saying take the component before squaring. So, it will be intact for acceleration, but should be 0 for slowing down. I know this topic is well researched, just want to find direct comparison of speeding and slowing at those speeds.

Comment: Kpv, *please* stop assuming that the people who work in this field are idiots. It's insulting. If these things didn't work symmetrically with the accelerating mode (and they do) there would be a Nobel prize in it for the person publishing an article on it. Accelerator physicists probably know the special theory better than anyone else because they interact with practical relativistic systems *every day of their working lives*. The problem here is not with the theory but that you are assuming that material written for general audiences cover every nuance of a big field. They don't.

Comment: @kpv If a force is applied opposite to a velocity, their dot product (i.e. the component of the force in the direction of the velocity) is certainly not zero. Its magnitude is the same as when the vectors are parallel, but its sign is different. Is that the source of the confusion here?

Comment: *"On v comment - I am saying take the component before squaring."* You seem to misunderstand how that works. Your way breaks even Newtonian mechanics.

Comment: @dmckee: My apologies if it seems insulting, I absolutely do not mean that. I also know pretty much I am wrong. But, isn't what I am suggesting is among the first tests that should have been done in order to prove the relativistic effect? Asking for as simple as this kind of experimental proof should not be considered insulting.

Comment: @dmckee: If I understand correctly, it breaks Newtonian mechanics only to the extent that relativistic effects break it. Which are negligible at slow speeds.

Comment: @kpv It "breaks Newtonian mechanics" (actually it breaks Math 101) because you are defining antiparallel vectors to be orthogonal.

Comment: Consider two vectors in 1D. $\vec{a} = +1$ and $\vec{b} = -2$. The component of $\vec{b}$ in the direction of $\vec{a}$ is $-2$. This is something that you need to be able to do fluidly and perfectly. There are *thousands* of things that have been tried in the realm of testing relativity that you will not find mentioned in general audience materials. We've been at this for *more than a century*. There is more than any summary could cover. There are tests that I've never heard of because I could never find the time to read a 800 page book on accelerator physics.

Comment: @dmckee: I get your points and may be the test that I am talking about has also been done. Just want to confirm. And it would not be a difficult test even if not done yet. For the vector issue: the component that contributes towards making the force ineffective and that ends at zero. I do not mean the vector sum, just the fact that only the positive component of $v$ in the direction of force would contribute to this effect. Zero and negative would not. The push speed maxes at $c$ in either direction. So, the negative component would be irrelevant. Do you think this test would be interesting?

Comment: You are simply wrong about the vectors. This is intro class stuff and you *really* need to get it right before you try to reason about more difficult concepts. Because you *must* be using the same understanding of what the math means as the people who wrote the math or communication has broken. The component of velocity in the direction of a force slowing the particle down is $-v$, not $0$ (or the component of force in the direction of velocity is $-F$). As long as you insist on that, this isn't even a well formed question.

Comment: @dmckee: Yes, you are right about the vector component. What I am describing is slightly different issue than vectors. Let me try again - 1) If the particle moving in direction of force, the force is effective per the formula. 2) Now imagine reducing $v$. 3) As $v$ reduces, the force becomes more and more effective. 4)When $v$ reaches 0, the force is 100% effective. 5) Now when $v$ goes to negative, the force still remains 100%effective as it can not exceed 100% effectiveness. So, negative $v$ and zero $v$ are same for the effect that I am talking about.

Comment: @dmckee: If the original momentum formula is derived in terms of vectors, then I agree that there will be a disconnect between original momentum math and the force math that I have used.

Comment: The force is 100% effective at changing momentum all the time. It's just that momentum and velocity are not related in the familiar Newtonian way—the way that seems to make logical sense simple because we only experience low relative velocities. You are trying to force a Einsteinian world into a Newtonian context by bending several concepts out of shape, and it doesn't work because the world is not Newtonian and never has been. We were just fooled for a long time because we could only do experiments in case where $v_\text{rel} \ll c$.

Comment: @dmckee: Yes, yes, yes, my whole point is to test confirm whether the force is 100% effective all the time or it is rendered less effective when particle is already moving in direction of the force, which can also give impression of different relation between momentum and velocity. That is why I proposed the experiment that gains negligible velocity and large momentum during last 1 minute of accelerating and then check how much velocity is lost during next 1 minute of slowing down using same but opposite force. I am stuck at this, please help if you can dig this evidence.

Comment: @MarkMitchison: I am not considering dot product. I am not even considering vectors throughout. Please read my comments with dmckee for what I am talking about. My apologies for late response, I did not want to make it confusing by mixing comments.

Comment: Also see my answer here, I work out Newtons's equation in simple relativity in the case of constant force. Just put -F instead of F (and integrate dv/dt from 0 to t, remembering $v(0)$ ia now not 0) if you want to see what happens when the force slows the particle down... http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/227791/un-perfect-vacuum-no-external-force-if-i-apply-a-small-amount-of-force-to-a-b/291061#291061

Comment: I developed your question a bit; http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/307202/relativity-what-actually-happens-if-the-lorentz-transformation-lorentz-boost

Comment: @dmckee: Did you get busy?

Comment: @dmckee: I was able to check with Brookhaven National Laboratory and also with CERN. They both confirmed that they do slow down particles pretty frequently and the symmetry of the formula is experimentally verified. Thanks for your patience.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question is founded on an incorrect assumption.

The math absolutely *is* symmetric between acceleration and deceleration (because velocity enters in to the Lorentz factor squared), and we have machines that take advantage of this fact.

[Energy recovery linacs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy_recovery_linac) work in exactly the manner linacs usually work, only the field timing is maintained 180 degrees out of phase from the acceleration mode. This means that instead of the particle gaining energy at the expense of the field, the field gains energy at the expense of the particle. The forces are the same as in the accelerating case only opposed to the direction of motion, and the particle exhibits the same magnitude of coordinate acceleration (i.e. very little because it is highly relativistic) in the lab frame only slowing rather than speeding up.

Answer (score 4):

The mass does not approach infinity. The mass, more precisely the [invariant mass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariant_mass), is a constant. What happens is the the momentum approaches infinity.

The momentum of an object of mass $m$ moving at velocity $v$ is:

$$ p = \gamma m v = \frac{mv}{\sqrt{1 - \frac{v^2}{c^2}}} $$

which goes to infinity as $v \to c$. In the limit of $v \ll c$ the Lorentz factor $\gamma \approx 1$ and we recover the Newtonian approximation.

Force is the rate of change of momentum, so if you apply a constant force the momentum will increase linearly with time. However for any finite force applied for a finite time the momentum can never reach infinity so the velocity can never reach $c$.

Comment: So, if we keep applying force for a long time, and say speed does not change, or changes just a little to remain below c, where does the energy imparted by force goes to? Does it keep accumulating with the particle? Secondly, after the speed stabilizes at close to c, keep applying the force for one more hour. Suppose speed changes negligible during this one hour. Now reverse the same force to slow it down. Will speed decrease by same negligible amount during one hour? What does math says and what does experiments say if there have been any?

Comment: @kpv the energy is given by $E^2 = p^2c^2 + m^2c^4$, so as $p \to \infty$ also $E \to \infty$

Comment: Please see if you can answer second part of my previous comments.

Comment: Re second part: $F = dp/dt$. If you push with force $F$ then $dp/dt$ is positive. If you pull with force $F$ then $dp/dt$ has the same magnitude but is negative.

Comment: John Rennie, I expected same mathematically. Are you aware of any experiments done on this at speeds closer to c? My instinct says, the pull will slow down much faster at those limits. Have experiments been done to prove it is not the accelerating force that is rendered mostly ineffective at those speeds? The slowing down force should be relatively more effective.

Comment: The LHC accelerates particles very, very close to $c$ every day (though I don't think it slows them down again) so the process I've described is verified all the time.

Comment: Yes, for accelerating, it is a daily routine. I meant comparing accelerating and slowing down near the limits. It would be really interesting to know, if it is not so hard to test. Do you know how to check with them if they have done it, or how to tell them to do so if they have not.

Comment: How could the slowing down possibly be different to the accelerating? The same laws of physics apply, it's just a change in sign of the force. What possible mechanism could there be for making the acceleration and deceleration asymmetric?

Comment: My instinct (I know instincts are usually mistaken), is same argument - due to comparable speed of that of the force itself, the accelerating force is rendered ineffective. In a way, we can not accelerate a car that is already going at 300 miles/hr by pushing with our hands, but we can accelerate a car going at 5 miles an hour. Slowing down is not impacted whether the car is going at 5 or 50 miles an hour. as long as force is effective, it is rate of change of p. I think at limits, slowing force is effective and accelerating force is mostly ineffective. I know weird but no harm in testing.

Comment: As the speed gets closer and closer to that of force (c), the force can not push it any more. Same way as we can not move our hand faster than 300 miles/hr and can not accelerate that car by pushing on it. But slowing down would be effective (dangerous and fatal though).

Comment: John Rennie, same math can be applied to effectiveness of the force except that you have to take component of v which is in direction of the force. So in case of slowing down it will be zero. Thus the law/math does not change either.

Comment: @kpv The field effect laser installation at Jefferson Lab is an example of a facility that *slows* a highly relativistic beam using the same mechanism they initially used for speeding it up. They even recover some of the energy input that way. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy_recovery_linac .

Comment: @JohnRennie: I was able to check with Brookhaven National Laboratory and also with CERN. They both confirmed that they do slow down particles pretty frequently and the symmetry of the formula is experimentally verified. I have accepted dmckee's answer as we had a longer exchanges. Thanks.

Answer (score -6):

[According to my understanding](https://www.researchgate.net/project/QED-Theory-of-everything), you can't calculate these separately, you always have to hold the complete picture in mind, thus not only the [momentum ("mass") approach infinity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_in_special_relativity), but also  [Length Contraction.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Length_contraction) and [Time dilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_dilation) happens.

This means that as momentum, is $p=mv$ and $v=l/t$,

1. Length contraction;
   So as this Length $l$ approaches zero, then any *time* would cause the velocity be zero too.
2. Time Dilation;
   or this $t$ approaches infinity, and again any *lenght* would cause the velocity to be zero.

But if velocity is zero, then also $p=mv$ should be zero, no matter what is the mass! So something must be wrong here! (not to forget that all this stuff is still "agreeing with the experiments")

The Mass is wrong. There is no mass at all. And thus the "momentum" is in troubles with photon. [Photon has momentum, but no mass.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photon#Physical_properties) 
There is no mathematically solid explanations for this.

What happens, in the speed of light, or in photon emission, is that the volume of a particle goes to zero. This is easy to understand with the length contraction.

$$ L = L_0\sqrt{1 - \frac{v^2}{c^2}} $$

No matter what is the area, if height is zero, volume is zero. When volume approaches zero, the *density* approaches infinity, if we hold the idea of some "invariant mass". And this is what is observed in the experiments.

But mass is a pseudo thing, If you just think the [Newton's 3rd law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_laws_of_motion#Newton.27s_3rd_Law) for while, you might realize that; total mass is zero, as every "mass" has equal negative "mass".

Comment: I developed this with my own question; http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/307202/relativity-what-actually-happens-if-the-lorentz-transformation-lorentz-boost

Answer (score -7):

Einstein's mass-velocity relationship, as given above by John Rennie, is a simple mathematical formula that comes from the special theory of relativity. It does not take into account the matter-wave duality and energy-temperature relationship, as given by the Maxwell-Boltzman formula.

$E = m(v) \cdot c^2$; $E= hf$ and $E= KT$ are three fundamental relationships. As the energy of a particle is increased, the associated matter-wave frequency and temperature also increase. Both of these factors increase the energy radiated by the mass to the surrounding. If these two properties of matter will not be there, it will not be possible to convert matter into energy. Einstein's mass-velocity formula, also does not take into account the fact that all matter contain an equal amount of positive and negative charges. These charges produce rotating Electro-Magnetic waves. Increasing the velocity of a particle produces EM waves in the form of spirals -- like the grooves in a cork-screw...These also contribute to the radiation of Energy ,in the form of EM waves to the surrounding.

So , as the velocity of a particle increases ,the Energy  radiate by it to the surrounding also increases. 
 This problem , has not been studied by the Scientists in detail ...So no Mathematical formula relating Particle Velocity to the Energy Radiated by it , is available at present . 
 This is  precisely  what ,  has prevented scientists and Engineers from generating Fusion Energy , with the help of Tokamak.s .

Comment: I promise you can answer this question without thermodynamics.

Comment: When you are talking about Physical objects taking Infinite value , because of application of Mathematics , opinions will  vary ..Mathematicians use " Infinite" freely , but when you  consider applied Mathematics , concept of Infinite , gives rise to a lot of problems. Sometimes it is not possible to experimentally  verify these mathematically derived conclusions. eg.-an Ideal Voltage Source has Infinite Charge and Infinite Capacitance --unrealisable ,but an integral part of Electrical Engg.Theory .

Comment: Sahu. Recommend you take a physics 1 course, you'll learn something and eventually see how wrong you are. As the energy of a particle is increased, in vacuum (there's no consideration of air or anything else needed to answer this basic physics question) the temperature does not change. Also your first equation is wrong. Best to start from scratch.