# Relativity, What actually happens if the Lorentz transformation. Lorentz boost

Tags: lorentz-symmetry

If we look the relations of [Lorentz Boost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_transformation#Physical_formulation_of_Lorentz_boosts); 
$$t'=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}} (t-\frac{vx}{c^2})$$
$$x'=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}} (x-vt)$$
$$y'=y$$ $$z'=z$$

we can concentrate on 2D case, and as $$v=\frac{ax}{bt}$$ and 
$$v'=\frac{ax'}{bt'}$$
Here $a$ is some certain numeric amount of length, and $b$ some certain numeric amount of time, so that $0<v=\frac{a}{b}<c$, ofcource the $x$ and $t$ could have been directly such amounts. By using $a$ and $b$ it can be prevented that something in the calculation becomes "[Geometrized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometrized_unit_system)".

then we can write; 
$$t'=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{(\frac{ax}{bt})^2}{c^2}}} (t-\frac{(\frac{ax}{bt})x}{c^2})$$
$$x'=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{(\frac{ax}{bt})^2}{c^2}}} (x-(\frac{ax}{bt})t)$$

And these Reduce a bit to; 
$$t'=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{(\frac{ax}{bt})^2}{c^2}}} (t-\frac{\frac{ax^2}{bt}}{c^2})$$
$$x'=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{(\frac{ax}{bt})^2}{c^2}}} (x-\frac{ax}{b})$$

Wo when these are combined to $v'$ then
$$v'=\frac{\frac{a}{\sqrt{1-\frac{(\frac{ax}{bt})^2}{c^2}}} (x-\frac{ax}{b})}{\frac{b}{\sqrt{1-\frac{(\frac{ax}{bt})^2}{c^2}}} (t-\frac{\frac{ax^2}{bt}}{c^2})}$$

Which can be written; 
$$v'=\frac{a(x-\frac{ax}{b})}{\sqrt{1-\frac{(\frac{ax}{bt})^2}{c^2}}} \frac{\sqrt{1-\frac{(\frac{ax}{bt})^2}{c^2}}}{b(t-\frac{\frac{ax^2}{bt}}{c^2}) }$$

And this reduces quickly just to; 
$$v'=\frac{a(x-\frac{ax}{b})}{1} \frac{1}{b(t-\frac{\frac{ax^2}{bt}}{c^2}) }=\frac{a(x-\frac{ax}{b})}{b(t-\frac{ax^2}{btc^2})}$$

And
$$v'=\frac{ax-\frac{a^2x}{b}}{bt-\frac{bax^2}{btc^2}}=\frac{ax-\frac{a^2x}{b}}{bt-\frac{ax^2}{tc^2}}$$

**So, this would be the Lorentz -Transformation for velocity;**
$$v'=\frac{ax-\frac{a^2x}{b}}{bt-\frac{ax^2}{tc^2}}$$

**Question;**
Are these kind of higher level Lorentz Transformation been properly analysed before? (Source)
1. Velocity
2. Acceleration
3. [Jerk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jerk_(physics))
**4. Momentum**

Comment: What are $a$ and $b$?

Comment: For velocity transformation (the correct formula), see for example [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Velocity-addition_formula).

Comment: The relative velocity is the same in both frames (same magnitude opposite direction)

Comment: @MarkH  a is some value for length, and b is some value for time. They could also be chosen in away that makes "c"     -at claude chuber, thanks. But I wanted to maintain the velocity in a Length/Time -format, so that the true changes would be shown. - at John Rennie, Thanks, But are there any deeper meaning in ie. length variation which is revealed ($a^2$) when written as in question.

Comment: It is unclear what a and b are (a change of units?). I did not follow your derivation but there must be a mistake somewhere, as the rule for speed transformation does not reduce to the correct on for a=b=1.

Comment: @AlbertAspect Well, this was exactly what I wanted to avoid, that these are geometrized somewhere in the calculation; a=b=1

Comment: Ok, I now understand why you generalized and included a and b to get a generalized transformation. However, I am not sure to understand why you claim that the equation should not reduce to the standard one for a=b=1

Comment: @AlbertAspect I don't understand it either. That's why I am asking. Or as I understand it, the whole concept of relativity has something which is not quite in order. And this is what I am trying to dig out here. In comments given velocity transformation link is not handling it in this level. I mean if velocity is L/T, I want to see What actually changes, and how.  This question gave me the inspiration; http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/306438/clarification-on-infinite-mass-momentum-argument

Comment: I'll try to find what is the mistake in your derivation later.

Comment: The error I found is that you is that used v, the speed between the two reference frames  as if it were the same that the speed v observed for an object in that same reference frame. Under such assumption in the primed reference frame the observed speed will reduce to zero, which agrees with your equations, which reduce to v'=0 when a=b=1. So, I guess you equations might be correct.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your derivation starts before you attempt to generalize by defining speed as
$$v = \frac{x}{t}.$$
This is incorrect because $x$ and $t$ are coordinates, not lengths or durations. In your final expression, the velocity is a function of time, which shouldn't be the case if the velocities are constant. The proper definition of velocity is
$$v = \frac{x_2 - x_1}{t_2 - t_1}$$
or, for instantaneous velocity,
$$v = \frac{dx}{dt}.$$

So, the proper procedure to find the velocity transformation (well, one procedure), is to define an object in the primed frame traveling at a constant velocity $v'$ with respect to that frame.
$$v' = \frac{dx'}{dt'}.$$
Then, you can solve for the speed in the unprimed frame by solving the Lorentz boost equations for the unprimed $x$ and $t$ in terms of their primed coordinates and calculating
$$v = \frac{dx}{dt}.$$
Note that, due to the chain rule, you'll need the expression for
$$\frac{dt'}{dt},$$
which is the time dilation factor.

Comment: Thanks for the answer; x is just a coordinate? I need to absorb this a bit, but I upvote  cause this answer is useful.  ... If x is just a coordinate, then it would mean that the position is depending form the velocity?

Comment: @JokelaTurbine Yes. x, t, x', and t' are all coordinates specifying the current position in space and time (spacetime if you want to be fancy) in different reference frames: x and t in one, x' and t' in the other. In special relativity, a reference frame is a coordinate system with inertial motion (not accelerating). For me, it helps to imagine an observer at the origin of the reference frame in order to imagine what she sees. (continued)

Comment: @JokelaTurbine The variable v is usually taken to be the velocity of one reference frame in terms of one defined to be at rest. The designation of "at rest" is arbitrary. You could just as easily say the "at rest" frame is really moving at -v velocity according to the "moving" frame (hence the name relativity). (continued)

Comment: @JokelaTurbine As to your question: "it would mean that the position is depending form the velocity?" the answer is yes. If an object has a non-zero velocity, then its position x must be changing with time t. However, an object that is moving in one frame may be at rest in another. You always have to specify what an object is moving with respect to, since every object is at rest in its own reference frame.